# echo specific item from multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Been hammering away at this for weeks.  I think it's actually simple...but I just can't get it.

I want to pull info from the database and use it in divs later on in my html.  I've been successful in other cases looping through and displaying the full results of a query in the past.  In this case I just want to echo a specific team name or team ID in my html.  All the data gets used...so I'd like to just have one query, but the data gets used in different divs in different places...so being able to echo specific parts of the query is important.

The query I have returns 10 rows and 4 columns.

```
<?php

$playoffs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT playoffseed, ttName, teamID, ttsUID
                            FROM standings
                            WHERE ttsUID = $season_view
                            AND playoffseed > 0
                            ORDER BY playoffseed
                            LIMIT 10");
?>
```

Now, I think I've learned that this query returns a result set and not an array.  It needs to be processed using some php to turn it into an array.  Correct?  And given the fact it's got multiple columns and rows once it is processed it would be a multidimensionsal array.  Ok I've scoured this site and google...tried many ideas using mysqli_fetch_array, mysqlifetch_assoc, and any other mysqli_fetch that I'd come across.

In my mind anyway, after processing the query with some php I'm thinking the array would look like this...

```
playoffseed  ttName    teamID    ttsUID
1            Buffalo   13        1993
2            Miami     19        1993
3            Detroit   8         1993
4            Denver    3         1993
5            Chicago   26        1993
...and so on.  10 rows total
```

After that I'd like to be able to call on (echo) various items from the above in my html.  Let's say in one div I'd like to be able to echo the ttName "Detroit" and then to call and image associated with the teamID I'd like to be able to call that too (it'd be something like this in my html...

```
IMG SRC="../images/<?php echo "teamID" ?>.jpeg
```

...where in this case Detroits image is "8.jpg").

How can that be done?  How do I correctly fetch the array and then echo a specific item of data from it?

I'm thinking if the above is an associated array I'd be able to echo something like this to return "Detroit"...

```
echo $playoffs[3]['ttName'];
```

[3] = 3rd row and ['ttName'] = column.  no?  I realize that [3] would actually refer to the 4th row if it's actually pointing to rows that start with zero and not one, but I'd like to be able to call on the item by using the "playoffseed" identifier, but I'm just too confused at this point.

I already feel I've made this question too confusing in itself.  Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: could you provide more PHP code here?

Comment: so your question is, how would you echo the `teamId` and use it as a part of a source on a `<img>` tag?

Comment: question is #1. How to turn the query result into an array, and #2. How to echo any specific part of that array.

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_assoc to process the query result?  and then how to echo an item from that array.

Comment: this could shed some light to you http://us2.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: been there a 100 times.  i'm just not getting something.  long story short in case the above is too much....take query and process it with php to create an array...then echo....say..."detroit" from that array.

Comment: echo '<pre>' . print_r($playoffs) . '</pre>' should give you the structure of your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**kevinabelita:**

> this could shed some light to you [us2.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php](https://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

**OP:**

> been there a 100 times. i'm just not getting something. long story short in case the above is too much....take query and process it with php to create an array...then echo....say..."detroit" from that array

And still didn't notice this simple way?

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($playoffs)) {
            $values[]=$row;
            echo $row["ttName"];
            //print_r($row);   // if you want to see all the data this row contains
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Now you can use $values with an index like you wish. i.e.

```
echo $values[0]["ttName"];
```

**Edit**

I mistakenly was trying to execute the query again. Fixed in the code above. Now for a little explanation of what you are confused with. Here's how the flow goes roughly

- Connect to the database
- Prepare/Run a query    (`mysqli_query` in this case)
- Store the result resource In a variable    (`$playoffs` in this case)
- Either fetch all rows from that result all together or fetch one by one. In this case `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in a loop is fetching the rows one by one till all of the result set has been fetched.
- Provide that fetched row as an array for you to use, in that case its stored in `$row` variable.

Comment: Yeah I had it there before but then thought it might become like too many things at once. Lemme add it back

Comment: correct.  mysqli_fetch_assoc processes the query turning it into an array correct?

Comment: if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $playoffs)) {.........this line is giving an error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given" is shown in the browser and in netbeans "accidental assignment in a condition $result=mysqli_query($con, $playoffs)"

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake you have already executed the query. One second let me update

Comment: Oh thank god.  Thanks for your time.  I've been really hung up on that.  I couldn't pull that info from the php manual page.  I'll study your explanation and learn from it.  For now it does what I need it to do.  Carry on!